Ubuntu 22 doesnot go to sleep when screen lid is closed
I have MSI katana GF66 and recently installed Ubuntu 22.40 in it. When I closes my lid, it doesnt go to sleep instead it still uses the system's battery. I have confirmed that because when I put it in my bag, aftersome time due to heat fans starts running at max speed. It eventually drains all my battery. Is there anyway I can resolve this issue ?
